# SageMaker Monitoring Tutorial boto3 Object Function Type Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, typeerror, monitoring, amazon-sagemaker

I am following the steps in the SageMaker Monitoring Tutorial here:
https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sagemaker_model_monitor/introduction/SageMaker-ModelMonitoring.html

And for the line:

```
bucket.Object(code_prefix + "/preprocessor.py").upload_file("preprocessor.py")
```

I get the error:

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Which I dont understand, because the input to the `upload_file()` function is `"preprocessor.py"` which is  a string.

Comment: The link to the tutorial is broken, could you please share the updated link/code you are using?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @RaghuRamesha. I have corrected the link.

Answer (score 0):

To unblock you quickly, please take the sagemaker session route to upload the artifact to S3 bucket  -

```
import sagemaker
from sagemaker import get_execution_role

# S3 bucket for saving code and model artifacts.
# Feel free to specify a different bucket and prefix
bucket = sagemaker.Session().default_bucket()

artifact_name = "preprocessor.py"
prefix = "code" // change as required

sample_url = sagemaker.Session().upload_data(
    artifact_name, bucket=bucket, key_prefix=prefix"
)
```